# Disappear a button in Python-selenium Headless Testing

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, headless-browser

I try to scrape [this site](http://www.cdiscount.com/mpv-32672-Alimentaire--Express--Montmartre.html?TechnicalForm.SiteMapNodeId=257027&TechnicalForm.DepartmentId=&TechnicalForm.ProductId=&hdnPageType=StoreSeller&TechnicalForm.SellerId=32672&TechnicalForm.PageType=MARKETPLACE_SELLERSHOP&NavigationForm.CurrentSelectedNavigationPath=f%2F1%2F2d&FacetForm.SellerId=32672&FacetForm.SelectedFacets.Index=0&FacetForm.SelectedFacets.Index=1&FacetForm.SelectedFacets.Index=2&FacetForm.SelectedFacets.Index=3&SortForm.SelectedSort=PRODUCTNAMEASC&ProductListTechnicalForm.Keyword=&PaginationForm.CurrentPage=1&PaginationForm.TotalPage=20&&_his_) with Python-selenium, my problem is when i launch my script in local it works and i scrape all the articles, but when i launch my script in server, i should run my code  Headlessly with Xvfb

```
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()
```

and in this case, the NEXT PAGE button disappear and my script can't click in next page button.

i try to click

```
xpath_path = 'a.jsNxtPage.pgNext'
      try:
          element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, xpath_path)))
      finally:
          driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element)
```

it works in local but not when i use Headless Testing  in server

i tried also with chrome and firefox.

Comment: Why is not working in Headless Testing in server?? is there any exception or something else??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur because the NEXT PAGE button disappears " i took a screen shot", but when i use normal webdriver in local  i see the process i see the next page and everything works.

Comment: instead of `presence_of_element_located` try using `element_to_be_clickable` as `element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, xpath_path)))
element.click()` and let me know

Comment: @SaurabhGaur did you recieve my answer? your answer is deleted